# Problems with Python installing anything

Tags: python

Ubuntu 16.04. I made virtualenv with python 3.6.5 . Inside virtualenv I typed:

```
pip install scrapy
```

this is **OUTPUT**:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting scrapy
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/scrapy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/scrapy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/scrapy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/scrapy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/scrapy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/scrapy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/scrapy/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scrapy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for scrapy
```

Scrapy is only example. When I want install anything I have this type of error. If You have any questions about this problem, please ask me.

Comment: The problem is pretty clearly that Python's ssl module is not installed… How did you install Python exactly?

Comment: I installed it from official site. I did it long time ago. I don't remember exactly how I did it